# Browser Caching Versions in Google Chrome with Tampermonkey

Tags: browser-cache, tampermonkey, versions, multiple-versions

I have a question about caching versions of imported files (via web requests) in Google Chrome:

Let's say I have `script.js`, whose URL is:
`http://www.getscripts.com/script.js` (URL contents arbitrary after "http://", because TamperMonkey imports over the HTTP protocol)

If I import the script in Tampermonkey using `@require`, I want to use a query string for its version to avoid caching.

**Caching versions:**

Let's say, that I first `@require` the 1st "version" of the script (created it, and inserted initial content), by giving the `require` a URL of `http://www.getscripts.com/script.js?v=1`, so I pass in the URL a query string of the version `v=1`, and that *the script file of version `v=1` was not cached already*.

I make some changes to the code of `script.js`, and the script that the URL provides also gets updated (I use [surge.sh](http://surge.sh)).

Then, I change my `@require` URL to: `http://www.getscripts.com/script.js?v=2`, so I pass in the URL a query string of the version `v=2`

Then I make some more changes in the code, make sure the URL gets the updated file, and give the `@require` my initial URL with `v=1`: `http://www.getscripts.com/script.js?v=1`

**Question:**

The script file that will be returned (via an HTTP request) - will it be of version 1, or 2?

What I'm doing is trying to force-download a new version of my script file, after I update the script's code, since Tampermonkey caches script files without re-downloading them, unless there was some changes made in the URL of the `@require` (what does the HTTP request).

Comment: Use the version parameter as a version. It should increase to be recognized as new.

Comment: Alright, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by forcing the browser to download a new version of the script by adding a version parameter to the script's URL, as suggested by wOxxOm above.